# XML encoder or Binary encoder? - Eclipse Milo (Client-Server)

Tags: java, eclipse, opc, opc-ua, milo

Eclipse Milo supports XML encoding if I'm correct. I want to make use of this XML encoding and changed the getEndpoint addres from **opc.tcp://server** ~binary to **http://server** ~web.

[image: Eclipse Code]

Before I'm continuing my assignment I wanted to make sure if it really worked. Because in the console log I see this result.

[image: Console Log]

I'm connecting to a S7-1500 PLC(server) with an opc **opc.tcp** address. But the connection can still be made even if the endPoint(in Milo) is set on http.

My question is how is this possible and is the XML encoding really active now?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) it does not matter whether you get the endpoints using a discovery endpoint that starts with "opc.tcp:" or "http:" - the resulting list of endpoints should be the same, and will contains endpoints with various protocols and various  encodings.

2) the encoding is not directly dependent on the protocol - while there are common combinations (profiles) and opc.tcp: is usually used with binary encoding and http: with XML encoding, it does not have to be the case.

The bottom line is, if you need an endpoint that uses binary encoding, your filtering code that chooses the right endpoint should check precisely for that (right now it looks only for a specific security policy)

Comment: First... Thanks for answering!

1) So if I'm understanding this right it uses the address without looking specifically at the protocol because it is not coded in the filter. So if I would add "http" in the filter it would make use of a XML encoder

2) I understand this part thanks.

Comment: ad 1) Yes, if you make an assumption that "http:" in the URL will give you the XML encoding, or at least the encoding that you want. If you want to be precise, you can look at the TransportProfileUri in the EndpointDescription; the one you are looking for may be e.g. WsHttpXmlTransport = "http://opcfoundation.org/UA-Profile/Transport/soaphttp-wssc-uaxml" .

Comment: Thanks ZbynekZ I'll try it out ^^

Comment: I'd like to add that unless you have some strange requirement the XML encoding should not be used. The binary encoding is much more performant. Further... the XML encoder/decoder is not fully implemented in Milo. I'd be surprised if the server in the S7-1500 exposed endpoints that used the XML encoding.